# Django unit tests - querying test database content

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Can someone point me to a resource, which shows how to query a Django test Database's specific table, during a unit test?

I have the following test code:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from users.models import User

class DisputeAssignerTestSuite(TestCase):

    databases = [
        'default', 
        'read_replica',
        ]

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.users = UserFactory.create_batch(50)

    def test_firstOne(self):
        print(users)
        print(User.objects.all())
```

UserFactory code:

```
import factory
from faker import Factory
import pytz

from users.models import User

faker = Factory.create()

class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        django_get_or_create = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'timezone', 'locale')

    first_name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.first_name())
    last_name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.last_name())
    display_name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: _.first_name + " " + _.last_name)    
    timezone = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.timezone())
    locale = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.random_choices(elements=('en-au', 'en-us', 'de-de', 'fr-fr'), length=1))
    password = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.password(length=12))
    last_login = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.past_datetime(start_date="-60d", tzinfo=pytz.timezone(faker.timezone())))
    is_superuser = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.boolean(50))
    email = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.email())
    username = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: _.email)
    is_staff = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.boolean(50))
    is_active = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.boolean(50))
    date_joined = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: faker.past_datetime(start_date="-1y", tzinfo=pytz.timezone(faker.timezone())))
```

I do not understand, how I can query User table in the test Database created by Django for this TestCase run, and e.g. verify its contents to some specific requirement (e.g. presence of users by a specific first name etc.).

When I write:

```
print(User.objects.all())
```

I get output of the production DB.

Help!

UPDATE:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': global_config['postgresql']['database'],
        'USER': global_config['postgresql']['user'],
        'PASSWORD': global_config.get('postgresql', 'password'),
        'HOST': global_config['postgresql']['host'],
        'PORT': global_config['postgresql']['port'],
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 30,
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'mytestdatabase',
        },
        'OPTIONS': {
            'connect_timeout': 60,
            'sslmode': 'prefer'
        },
    },
    'read_replica': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': global_config['postgresql']['database_read_replica'],
        'USER': global_config['postgresql']['user_read_replica'],
        'PASSWORD': global_config.get('postgresql', 'password_read_replica'),
        'HOST': global_config['postgresql']['host_read_replica'],
        'PORT': global_config['postgresql']['port_read_replica'],
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 30,
        'TEST': {
            'MIRROR': 'default',
        },
        'OPTIONS': {
            'connect_timeout': 60,
            'sslmode': 'prefer'
        },
    }

REPLICA_DATABASES = ['read_replica',]
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'multidb.PinningReplicaRouter',
    ]
```

Comment: How do you start your tests? Are you using `manage.py` from the top level directory?

Comment: Yes, python manage.py test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after tinkering with this problem A LOT, I have finally found out, that 'multidb.PinningReplicaRouter' middleware for database routing was the source of the issue. When used on Django 2.2.11 & Python 3.7 in my case, it prevented proper routing of queries to the test database, and instead breached the PROD/DEV isolation layer, writing into ??? (hard to tell, since I couldn`t do a read back) and reading back from PROD database.

I have worked around the problem, by including the following decorator in front of Test Suites I wanted to run:

```
@modify_settings(DATABASE_ROUTERS={'remove': 'multidb.PinningReplicaRouter'})
class SomeTestSuite(TestCase):
    # some test logic
```

Hope it benefits someone in the future.